# Data fills Datagrid, but doesn't appear in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019

I am creating a string `List<>` that will then be called to fill a data grid based on the differences between to text documents. The data seems to be filling the Datagrid, but doesn't actually show up. I know that sounds confusing, but I have played with the background/foreground colors and it almost seems like they don't even affect it. I was able to get this to work with a textblock, but then I couldn't scroll.

EDIT: I edited this in attempts to get my reputation up. It dropped quite a bit in a short time. I am not sure if it's my code formatting or the nature of the question, but if anyone has advice I am willing to listen.

```cs
        string sSelectedFile;
        string sSelectedFolder;

        public static List<String> txt1 = new List<string>();
        public static List<String> txt2 = new List<string>();
        public static List<String> Diff = new List<string>();

        public static List<int> DifferenceCounter = new List<int>();

        public static List<int> IntDifferenceOccurance = new List<int>();


        //public static List<string> Diff;
        public ObservableCollection<CustomerInformation> CustomerInformationList { get; } = new ObservableCollection<CustomerInformation>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            //fbd.Description = "Custom Description"; //not mandatory

            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                sSelectedFolder = fbd.SelectedPath;
            else
                sSelectedFolder = string.Empty;

            Textbox2.Text = sSelectedFolder;
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
            choofdlog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
            choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

            if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                sSelectedFile = choofdlog.FileName;
            else
                sSelectedFile = string.Empty;


            Textbox2.Text = sSelectedFile;
        }



        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog choofdlog = new OpenFileDialog();
            choofdlog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt";
            choofdlog.FilterIndex = 1;
            choofdlog.Multiselect = true;

            if (choofdlog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                sSelectedFile = choofdlog.FileName;
            else
                sSelectedFile = string.Empty;


            Textbox3.Text = sSelectedFile;
        }




        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            FillListTxt1();

            FillListTxt2();


            compareStringList();

        }


        public void FillListTxt1()
        {

            txt1.Clear();


            try
            {

                var fileStream = new FileStream(Textbox2.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        txt1.Add(line);



                    }
                }

            }
            catch  (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;

            }




        }


        public void FillListTxt2()
        {


            txt2.Clear();

            try
            {

                var fileStream = new FileStream(Textbox3.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string line;
                    while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {



                        txt2.Add(line);





                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;

            }



        }
    public class CustomerInformation
    {

        public string GetDiff { get; set; }     

    }


         public void compareStringList()
        {



            Diff.Clear();


            string Text1;
            string Text2;
            string StillCounting = "Yes";

            int IndexTxt1 = 0;
            int IndexTxt2 = 0;

            int Counter = 0;


            Int32 length = txt1.Count;
            Int32 length1 = txt2.Count;

            while (StillCounting == "Yes")
            {

                if (length > IndexTxt1 & length1 > IndexTxt2)
                {

                    Text1 = txt1[IndexTxt1];
                    Text2 = txt2[IndexTxt2];

                    if (Text1 != Text2)
                    {

                        //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("There is a difference on line " +  IndexTxt1.ToString());


                        string DifferencesInList = "There is a difference on line " + IndexTxt1.ToString();

                        Diff.Add(DifferencesInList);




                        IndexTxt1 = IndexTxt1 + 1;
                        IndexTxt2 = IndexTxt2 + 1;

                        Counter = Counter + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        IndexTxt1 = IndexTxt1 + 1;
                        IndexTxt2 = IndexTxt2 + 1;

                    }



                }
                else
                {



                    StillCounting = "No";

                }






            }


            if (Counter == 0)
            {

                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("These are exactly the same");

            }


            FillDataGrid();


        }


    public void FillDataGrid()
    {




         Int32 length1 = Diff.Count;
         int countLength = 0;

         string Text2; 

         //Text2 = Diff[countLength];

         while (length1 > countLength)
         {


              CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();

              TempCust.GetDiff =  Diff[countLength];

              Differences.Items.Add(TempCust.GetDiff);

              Differences.MinRowHeight = 30;

              countLength = countLength + 1;

         }


         //Differences.DataContext = Diff;

    }
```

This is the XAML code for the Datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerInformationList,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" Grid.RowSpan="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Width="400" x:Name="Differences" Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" FontSize="16" Height="600" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <DataGrid.Resources>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">

                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>

                </Style>

                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">

                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightYellow"/>
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,1,2"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="400"/>

                </Style>

            </DataGrid.Resources>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <!-- Each row is one item from CustomerInformationList. That means each row is an instance of
        CustomerInformation. CustomerInformation has a property named GetDiff, and here is how we bind to that property. -->


            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The output fills the Datagrid, but doesn't show up. I apologize for the formatting errors. I am having a difficult time with getting them to be corrected. This should not be code.

Before button click

[image: Before button click]

After button click

[image: After button Click: Datagrid filled, but nothing showing up]

Comment: try with `ObservableCollection` instead

Comment: Do not add to `Differences.Items`. Instead, you need to bind or assign your collection to `Differences.ItemsSource`. Do you have a collection of items you want to display in the DataGrid? What is `TempCust.GetDiff`? Is that your collection?

Comment: I am not sure how to do that, do you have a useful link? The other thing I don't quite understand is I have another WPF that I use exactly the same as this one and it works perfectly.

Comment: Are you saying you're not sure how to answer my question about the collection of items, or you're not sure how to assign a reference to `Differences.ItemsSource`? You don't need a loop, by the way. No loop. Just assign the collection to `Differences.ItemsSource`.

Comment: `GetDiff'` is my list yes. Also, I have had this issue in the past I cannot use ItemSource. WPF visual studio 2019 does not let me use that no matter how hard I try.

Comment: `ItemsSource`. Two 'S's. ItemsSource. Items. Source. ItemsSource. It's the source for the items. Items is plural.

Comment: I don't know how to use `ObservableCollection`, also, I am filling the datagrid with data, but it just won't show up. The data is there just won't appear. That is what I am finding is so weird about all of this.

Comment: What is in `GetDiff`? What kind of item does it contain? What are the names of its properties or columns? Please show that.

Comment: There is all of the code besides the class and namespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's create an observable collection that we'll use to populate the DataGrid. Since your grid column binds to a property named `GetDiff`, and `CustomerInformation` has a property by that name, I'm going to guess that you want to populate the grid with that class.

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
//  I don't know how you're populating this list. I'm guessing that happens in 
//  compareStringList() and then you call FillDataGrid(). 
private List<string> Diff;
public ObservableCollection<CustomerInformation> CustomerInformationList { get; } 
    = new ObservableCollection<CustomerInformation>();

public void FillDataGrid()
{
    CustomerInformationList.Clear();

    foreach (var diff in Diff)
    {
        CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();

        TempCust.GetDiff = diff;

        CustomerInformationList.Add(TempCust);
    }
}
```

Now, let's use a binding to tell your DataGrid to use the collection property we created. Because you set `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` on your DataGrid, you don't need to create the columns yourself, but you had the binding , so I'm setting AutoGenerateColumns="False" and including the column definition.

```
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding CustomerInformationList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
    HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    Width="400" 
    x:Name="Differences" 
    Grid.Row="4" 
    Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
    FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1"
    >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <!-- Stuff omitted -->
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <!-- 
        Each row is one item from CustomerInformationList. That means each row is an instance of
        CustomerInformation. CustomerInformation has a property named GetDiff, and here is how we 
        bind to that property. 
        -->
        <DataGridTextColumn 
            Header="Difference On Lines" 
            Binding="{Binding GetDiff}" 
            FontSize="16" 
            Width="200"
            />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: My bad I forgot the most important part of the code. I just added it because I take the first list then the second list and I compare the string through the list. I then get the index of that list when they are different and am trying to display that.

Comment: I have to be able to pass a string through to this list.

Comment: Nevermind, that worked perfectly. Thanks @Ed Plunkett you're amazing! <3

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `string` to your `DataGrid` but bind to `GetDiff`.

Method "**FillDataGrid**"

```
CustomerInformation TempCust = new CustomerInformation();
TempCust.GetDiff =  Diff[countLength];
Differences.Items.Add(TempCust.GetDiff); // <-- here you are adding string
// change it to "Differences.Items.Add(TempCust);" and it should work
```

**XAML**

```
<!-- here you are binding to "GetDiff" -->
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Difference On Lines" Binding="{Binding GetDiff}" FontSize="16" Width="200"/>
```

Comment: This is me having tried it 10 different ways. Nothing seems to be working.